# Create loop to print out most common phrases python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to create a loop to print out the most common phrases with the counts 5 or greater and the rest to be bucketed into other category. How do I write the loop to print out the common phrases that have counts of 5 or more? This is my code so far:

```
import csv
#from sys import argv
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
#script, filename = argv
data = defaultdict(list)

class dictionary:
    with open ('practice.csv', 'rb') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       #text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
       next(reader, None) 
       for row in reader:
          data[row[2]].append(row[3])

       #text_file.write("%r" % data)

       #text_file.close()

   #print(data)

   text_file = open("count.txt", "w")
   data_count = Counter()
   for d in data.values():
      data_count += Counter(d)
   print data_count.most_common(5)
   text_file.write("%r" % data_count.most_common(5))
   text_file.close()
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: need  to create loop to only count common phrases that have shown up 5 or more times.

Comment: wait, `class dictionary:` ?? Do you mean `def`?

Comment: yes sorry i did mean def.